# adding char array to HashSet

Tags: java

I have a HashSet of Character and I am trying to do:

```
Collections.addAll(mySet, test.toCharArray());
        mySet.addAll(test.toCharArray());
```

why is it saying it is not applicable? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `toCharArray()` yields a `char[]`, not a `Character[]`. Java generics don't work with primitives, so I guess you need to add each element manually.

Comment: any other more efficient way of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon another open source library that provides a high performance collections for primitives -- HPPC http://labs.carrotsearch.com/hppc.html

They were motivated by performance issues on autoboxing, and well, having primitives directly supported in collections.

Looks pretty good.